# word for "splitting time between various tasks"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, nouns

What'd be a good word (noun) for "dividing one's time between various tasks"?

E.g., when you refer to an employee that works on several projects in a given month, but not necessarily on more than one activity at any given time.

*Multitasking* does not seem to be the best choice here. Any alternatives?

Comment: If you've rejected *multitasking* because you're only working on one thing at any given moment, how about ***timeslicing**?*

Comment: Why do you say "multitasking" does not seem to be the best choice here? What do you feel is inadequate about that word?

Comment: he/she (the employee) does not have to work on more than one task at a time (for example, one week on task A, three weeks on task B). I'm under the impression that _multitasking_ implies that (at least some of) the tasks overlap in time...

Comment: That could be considered "juggling projects" which has a high degree of informality.  Most employees have to do something called "time management" to allow enough time, through planning, for all the projects they are assigned to complete in any given period of time.

Comment: Several *irons in the fire.*  Means a few things going on simultaneously but not being hammered on the anvil at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Job rotation** (*mass noun*):

The practice of moving employees between different tasks to promote experience and variety

> '*Most employers in this sector focused on internal reshuffling and job rotation initiatives, instead of taking on new staff.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Types of rotation include:

**Task rotation**, which usually takes place in jobs that involve a high degree of physical demands on the body, or a high degree of repetitive tasks that can become extremely tedious.

**Position rotation** is the process of laterally moving an employee to different positions, departments or geographical locations for the purposes of professionally developing the employee by exposing them to new knowledge, skills and perspectives.

Source: [Study.com: Introduction to Management](http://study.com/academy/lesson/job-rotation-definition-advantages-disadvantages-examples.html)

Further information on job rotation is available at: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_rotation)

Comment: thanks, I think _job rotation_ is the best fit for what I was looking for.

Comment: You're very welcome, @user2186862. Glad to be of help:)

Answer (score 3):

In many industries a person who moves from task to task is known as a **floater**.

Floater: a worker who moves from job to job; especially without fixed duties
[ [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floater)]

Comment: thanks, but _floater_  has a negative connotation.

Comment: I've worked in businesses where a floater fills in for employees that are out on sick leave or taking vacation.  I didn't get a sense of that type of function from the OP.  The question sounds more like someone who's responsibilities include a number of different projects that all need to be worked on but not serially (in other words, they're not required to complete one before moving onto the others).

Answer (score 1):

*"dividing one's time between various tasks"*

You just described my daily life.

> I'm constantly "juggling" tasks and priorities throughout the day.

I'm not necessarily multitasking because I focus on the project at hand and shut everything else out. But I know that in a short while I'll be on another project.

Answer (score 0):

In computer science, we use **scheduling** referring to the management of resources (including human time) assigned to a given amount of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

**[monochronic:](http://study.com/academy/lesson/monochronic-vs-polychronic-cultures-definitions-communication-styles.html)** having a linear time orientation where only one thing can be accomplished at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In a software sort of context, something of this nature could be referred to as **Load Balancing** FWIW

Answer (score 0):

Process. (Processing) The art of moving from one task to another over the course of minutes or hours in a day, or days in a week, etc; not excluding overlapping tasks.