# What do you call a person whose job is to let their coworkers go on breaks/lunch?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say there's a workplace that needs constant attention from 10 people at different posts/locations. The company hires 11 people so the extra 11th person can go around letting the others take lunch breaks or rest. What do you call this extra job/person or the corresponding verb (could be from any industry you are familiar with)?
Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of this being a job. It just seems like one of the roles of a foreman or supervisor. I can't imagine hiring someone just do to this one thing.

Comment: @Barmar I've done this job.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think that *let* in the question means that the person issues permissions (that would indeed be something what a supervisor does), but rather that the person makes it possible for others to take their breaks by replacing each of them for the length of his/her break. If there are n people to be replaced and each person's break is 1/(n+1) of the workday, then this amount to a full time job.

Comment: @jsw29 That makes more sense. I thought they were telling people when it was their time for break.

Comment: My brother worked for some time as a postman, where the work is organised into "rounds", and most "posties" work 5 out of 6 days (no Royal Mail delivery on Sunday in the UK *yet!* :) Where he worked, the posties were organised into groups of six - five of whom each did their own round 5 days out of 6, and on each one's day off, the "floating" sixth postie did their round. That sixth guy was called the ***swing** postie* by the rest of the "team" (in a carefully managed relationship where the "swing" postie was normally expected to hand over or share in any Christmas bonus given by customers).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  "no Sunday delivery *yet*" - it's the other way round. There used to be Sunday deliveries, and tall deliveries per day, but now royal mail want to go down to 5/week.

Comment: @ChrisH: "go down to 5/week"??? I think not! I did actually know that [The Post Office / Royal Mail used to deliver on Sunday before WW1](https://kathleenmcil.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/the-post-office-and-sunday-deliveries-a-historical-perspective/), but it's only after being prompted by your comment that I've just discovered they've been "trialing" Sunday deliveries since 2014. My brother retired a couple of years after that, but he certainly never mentioned the possibility of *his* workplace being in that trial.

Comment: @FumbleFingers they're trialing Sunday parcels when it suits them, but they want to give up the obligation to deliver universally on Saturdays ([rejected for now](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2023/jun/08/uk-government-reject-royal-mail-request-end-saturday-deliveries)). So we're both right, but in different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

It's like a **relief position**. I also did this job once, when working in a department store. I would work wherever someone was needed due to illness, rest breaks, customer surge etc. My job title was **mobile**.

The closest [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mobile) definition was the adjective being used as a noun:

> **mobile**
>
> able to move or be transported easily from one place to another, or be used for a different purpose

Comment: I've often heard *relief* used as a noun in this case. "I can't leave until my relief gets here"; "Take your break, I'm your relief"

Comment: @JimMack yes that's true.

Answer (score 4):

The word that is **roughly** suitable for what the OP has in mind is ***floater***. See Zan MacArthur's answer to [word for "splitting time between various tasks"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262064/word-for-splitting-time-between-various-tasks/262075#262075), RyeɃreḁd's answer to [What is the word for a person who does different jobs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163213/what-is-the-word-for-a-person-who-does-different-jobs/163304#163304),  and vickyace's answer to [What is the word for "job-hopper" with a positive connotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383614/what-is-the-word-for-job-hopper-with-a-positive-connotation/383620#383620). (These answers are relevant here, but the OP's question is not a duplicate of the questions to which they were given as answers.)

The word may be the best for the purpose, but it is only roughly suitable for it, because its meaning is broader than what the OP has in mind here; it does not mean specifically that the person rotates through several positions in the course of each workday in order to make it possible for other worker's to take their breaks.